# Finding the Right Image-Matching Algorithm for Brightfield Microscopy Data

Tags: image-processing, cross-correlation

I work predominantly on single-particle-localization algorithms for microscopy data, but we're working to implement a few different methods to extend our tracking methods nicely into the z-axis.

One of a few methods we're looking into is comparing recorded brightfield data to a pre-recorded look-up table (LUT) of a similar sample imaged at regular intervals along the z-axis.  We are very much NOT the first ones to apply this tactic, but I am running into some issues regardless. The methods I'm talking about here are pretty simple all things considered, but I haven't worked a lot with them so I don't have much intuition for them yet.  There may be some simple approaches to alleviate my concerns that I'm simply unaware of.

We are ideally attempting to image fast dynamics so our exposure times are pretty low and we lose some of the fine features.  Our beads are also pretty small so the variation between images on the LUT are admittedly quite obscure.  (apologies for not normalizing the colorbar scales in these images)

[image]   [image]

Our first approach was using cross correlation to compare images, but we learned some time ago that wasn't an ideal approach.

[image]

A method we've been having a lot of luck with in other applications is applying a gradient filter like a Roberts cross to get the gradient components of the images, correlate the components of the new image and LUT separately, and then add those correlation results together.  This produces an identifiable curve that we can apply a threshold to in order to estimate the range where this bead is in z.

[image]

My big concern with this method is that it breaks down a bit when looking at an out of focus bead.

[image]  [image]

In this scenario, the bead should really correlate best with the lower end of the LUT, and we indeed see the correlation peak on the low end is much closer to the central one, but the central peak is still notably higher.  This would obviously lead to an incorrect identification in its position.

I'm in need of some suggestions I'm afraid.  Adjustments to the method I've presented or recommendations of altogether different methodologies are very much welcome.  I'm also expecting that the lack of variation in our LUT means we wont get a frame perfect registration.  Dialing back the number of images in that LUT is likely a guarantee moving forward.

Comment: Why cross correlation would not work?

Comment: We've seen that with some filtering it can work decently, but without any extra considerations, cross correlating the image with our LUT produces the jagged plot up above.

Comment: Are you interested in the displacement in one specific direction? The cross correlation between two images should be an image.

Comment: Apologies, I should have clarified further.  Each point on the plots displayed here are the maximum value of the resulting correlation image between the recorded data and a frame from the LUT

Comment: A frame in the LUT is a image in the same scale, given two images how do you calculate the maximum value?

Comment: Using scipys correlate2d, the resulting output image is the correlation values of different alignments of the new bead compared with a frame of the LUT based on the mode and boundary conditions of the function.  np.max then provides the correlation value of the "correct" alignment.